# Symbolic Link Directory or File confusion

Tags: unix, terminal, symlink

Symbolic Links are awesome but I seem to have trouble remembering how to know whether it is the directory or the actual files in the directory that will be symlinked to a new place.

In this situation, I have some files located at ~/Documents/WD/CS/CSlides and I wish to symlink them INTO this directory ~/Documents/PDF/DB/CS/CSlides

I tried this:

```
ln -s "~/Documents/WD/CS/CSlides/" "~/Documents/PDF/DB/CS/CSlides/"
```

But that just put a new CSlides folder inside the one at the destination. I just want the source CSlides files to be linked. Not the directory itself.

Any thoughts?

- This is about programming. I was trying to move so documents relating to my web development. Blimey, some peeps are a bit too pernickety but if it's closed then it's closed. I got it sorted out eventually. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "merge" directories, you have to link each file like this:

```
ln -s ~/Documents/WD/CS/CSlides/* ~/Documents/PDF/DB/CS/CSlides
```

Comment: Running that, I end up with a file entitled "*" as having been symlinked. I understand what it was trying to do but it didn't work

Comment: Well, don't remove it with `rm ~/Documents/WD/CS/CSlides/*` but use something like `rm -i ~/Documents/WD/CS/CSlides/?` !! Are you sure you did remove the double quotes from your command as I did ?